# Can we customize or configure RPC or method call in place of endpoint(URL) for Netflix Ribbon or Spring Cloud Gateway?

Tags: load-balancing, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-gateway, netflix-ribbon

In my project requirement, We need to distribute the load between two different micro services but call of the two microservices are not based on the endpoint(URL) but it is calling via it's SDK-Client.

Can we customize either of Netflix ribbon or Spring Cloud Gateway to achieve it or is there any other solution for this?

For details please refer this attachment:-[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIQ9p.png)

Any feedback are greatly appreciated, Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Comment: Gateway can only do http. But ribbon or Spring Cloud load balancer gan be used with anything. Inject a `LoadBalancetClient` or `ReactiveLoadBalancetClient` and call `choose()` that will give you an object with host and port.

Comment: Here HOST & PORT is black box as we are using two different SDK to call the API of MicroService-AA & MicroService-BB and we are just doing a normal method call of SDK to consume the services of MS-AA & BB from MS-XYZ(As per diagram). Mostly in place of two endpoint or server we want to use itsSdkClientAA & itsSdkClientBB